# Algorithm to turn a large blob of text into an image? (as defined by the image edges)

Tags: python, c, algorithm, image-processing

I have a large list of words that I am looking to display statistics of in an interesting fashion. I want to print each word, but with breaks at the edges of the image outline (designated by a certain color), such that overall all of the text forms the image.

I realize that's hard to grasp without an example, so pretty much what I want to achieve can be seen in [this image](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/1582/products/wonderland-2_570932c9-25d5-4a22-a660-cbd169515965_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1404880097) where the text of Alice in Wonderland is printed out to form an image of Alice and other creatures from the book; There's a whole lot of other examples at http://www.litographs.com/

I want to achieve the above programmatically, but I'm unsure of where to start on this initially. I started to write out a script that would parse through my image and print the text only corresponding to where transparent pixels are -- but I quickly realized that perhaps I don't really want to go based off of every pixel and instead perhaps an edge-detection based approach would be better. I'm also not sure how font size might factor in there.

Is there an algorithm out there that I am not aware of that might help me achieve this? I'm working with Python / C but I am happy to hear any solutions.

Comment: If you are looking for an algorithm that would achieve "something like" something you will fail because algorithms are deterministic. Instead please formalize your requirements.

Comment: A valid point akonsu. I want to achieve *exactly* what is displayed in the images, programmatically.

Comment: Why don't you just do it scanline by scanline? What you need is a function which measures the rendered width of the text; once you have that, it's more or less trivial.

Comment: Perhaps that is what I will do -- thanks for the idea! I suppose you're right about measuring the rendered width, that is the path I think I will head down.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to black/white, then convert to ascii art, then replace the ascii art with your text.

The black/white conversion is easy in PIL. I got the ascii art from https://github.com/hit9/img2txt/blob/master/img2txt.py

```
import Image

def to_ascii(img,maxLen=100.0):  

    #resize to maximum line length
    width, height = img.size
    rate = maxLen / max(width, height)
    width = int(rate * width)  # cast to int
    height = int(rate * height)

    img_small = img.resize((width, height))
    pixels = img_small.load()

    string = ""        
    for h in xrange(height):
        for w in xrange(width):
            rgb = pixels[w, h]
            if rgb == 0:
                string += ' '
            else:
                string += '#'
        string += "\n"

    return string

def hashes_to_text(hash_art, text):
    output = list(hash_art)
    tidx = 0
    for idx, char in enumerate(hash_art):
        if char == '#':
            output[idx] = text[tidx%len(text)]
            tidx += 1
    return ''.join(output)
```

Use it like:

```
#open your image file and convert to black/white
image_file = Image.open('Desktop/350px-Wiktionary_small.svg.png')
image_file = image_file.convert('1')  # to black/white

W = to_ascii(image_file)
W = hashes_to_text(W,'Wikipedia')
print W
```

Will convert this image

[image]

into

[image]

**Remark:** Look into [image segmentaion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation) algorithms to improve on the black/white conversion.

Comment: That's very pretty but it will only work with a fixed-width font.

Comment: That's a very clever method that I hadn't considered. Thanks very much!